# Changes made to shapefile

Tags: shapefile, editing, gis-principle, copy

If I take a Natural Earth shapefile and delete all countries except one - This will affect that original shapefile. Can I take that shapefile duplicate it and use that shapefile to delete all countries except one and then save that without affecting the original shapefile?

Comment: The confusion occurs when you make a GIS map project based on a single shapefile, make a copy of the map document, and edit the file data contents in the copy, and are surprised that the first map document is also affected. This gets to the heart of the difference between CAD and GIS, because the map document does not store the data, only pointers to where the data is located.  If you're making copies of the data, the copies do not maintain mystical bonds to their sources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I you copy the original shapefile (say countries_original.shp) so that you get a second shapefile (say countries_2.shp), than you can delete the countries there. This does NOT affect your original File countries_original.shp. There, you will still have all the original information. Be aware however that shapefiles consist of several files (at least three, often more), so copy all of them.

However, are you sure you want to have a second file with all countries but one deleted? This normally does not make sense - only if you want to reduce filesize. But if you duplicate (copy) your file, in the end you need more space on your drive. If you want to show just one country in your GIS-software (like QGIS), you can open the original Shapefile and define a filter, e.g. in the way that only the country with the name "Netherlands" will be displayed. So you have the same effect as with deleting all other files, but you don't have to change the original data.

Comment: +1 for not copying the data. That is almost always the wrong thing to do; you end up with a proliferation of datasets of unknown origin. Just use the original dataset and define ad hoc filters.

Comment: I know I can use a rules based expression for example in the attributes table I find the column with the countries name that i want to display, e.g Brazil I then use query builder to create an expresssion name = 'brazil' and then that would be the only country displayed - But if I have multiple layers where im doing this would all that data of the other countries not make my overall file size quite large and then slow to load - If i duplicate the shapefile and delete all of the other countries and do the same for multiple layers would this not reduce my file size ?

Comment: Your Shapefile is not saved in the QGIS-project (by the way: what software do you use - QGIS?). Of course, the bigger the file that you load gets, to longer it will take to load it. But this effect is quite neglectable if you don't have really very large files, the countries of the world should not be a real problem. If you have multiple layers, you still access always one and the same file. If you create a separate file for each country, you have to access as many files as you have countries. I doubt if that is more perfomant and effective.

Comment: In QGIS, you can use rule-based rendering so that you can define different styles for each country and filter only those you're interested in in just one layer, so you don't need several layers.